# Getting blank PHP page over Apache

Tags: php, apache, centos

In a newly setup digitalOcean cloud server (CentOS), I have installed php and Apache. The webserver is running fine:

```
[root@a2m5cent01 httpd]# service httpd status
httpd (pid  11232) is running...
[root@a2m5cent01 httpd]# php --version | head -1
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Dec 11 2013 03:29:57)
```

But browser is showing blank pages (white page) if I try to visit any php page.

Here is what I have done so far to troubleshoot:

1. Created a page with following content: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. It displays a blank page when viewed from browser.
2. Just to ensure, apache is pointing to the correct directory, placed a static `.html` page there, and saw it comes out fine in browser, so apache is working and directory is correct.
3. In `/etc/php.ini`, changed `display_errors` directive to `On`. Still blank page
4. In Apache config file (`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`) found this line `Include conf.d/*.conf`. Inside `conf.d` directory, there is a `php.conf` file containing the line:
   `LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so`. Ensured that this .so file actually exists in this place.
5. In the same file I have these two lines as well: `AddHandler php5-script .php` and `AddType text/html .php`
6. Executed the php page from CLI, it works fine - so php is working locally.

Then why is it always shows a blank/white page over the browser? What else am I missing?

**EDIT**
Based on suggestions from @Nathan,

1. I checked Apache error log file, could not see any error being
   reported there.
2. My `/etc/php.ini` says, php error_log is located as `syslog`. So I checked `/var/log/messages` but could not find any PHP error message
3. Next I put some normal `HTML` in the php file containing `phpinfo()` call. Interestingly I found that even the normal HTML texts are also not coming. It *still* produces blank page.
4. Then I checked Apache `access` log. Surprise! There is no `GET` request for any of the PHP files I tried to load in the browser. But **GET** request for all the **non-php** files are there with 200 return code.

Apache is **not** even logging any access request for PHP files. Any idea why would that happen?

Comment: @Dagon I thought I answered that in the first paragraph of my question. Yes, it is.

Comment: have you confirmed your http/php error logs show no message?  also for kicks I would add some HTML before and after the phpinfo() to confirm the page is loading but PHP is not running.

Comment: @Nathan Good points! I have updated my question with the details. Apparently Apache is not even registering any `GET` request for php files...

Comment: its interesting that a request is'nt logged.  do you recall which commands you ran and/or which packages you used installing PHP?  Or it may be easier to run ``yum list installed | grep "php" | less`` to see which PHP packages are installed.

Comment: php is certainly not configured with apache. I faced this problem in my vps too.

Comment: @DeSmOnd What do you mean? How do I confirm that? How did you solve your problem?

Comment: vps means virtual server. in short, i tried to install apache with php in my centos 6 os, but it always showed blank php, i.e, it couldnt understand the php files. then, i removed all related things like apache,php etc and installed from scratch like i said in my updated answer. Also, you need to do couple of thhings.

Comment: @Nathan using your command, I got these 3 packages: `php`, `php-cli`, `php-common`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been sometime, but I wanted to come back to this question to update that the issue was with the directory permission setup.

The FPM user I was using didn't have necessary permission to execute the `index.php` file in the web root.

To avoid these issues in the future, I have created an automated bash script that will automatically create and configure webservers in DigitalOcean boxes. Please take a look here https://github.com/akash-mitra/fairy

This script will automatically,

- Installs Nginx
- Create virtual server block for nginx
- Installs PHP, PHP APC, PHP Curl etc.
- Supports PHP Fast Process Manager (php-fpm)
- Installs Memcached
- Installs Database (MariaDB / MySQL)
- Optionally Installs PHP Composer and Laravel
- Configures and Strengthens SSH
- Activates Firewall
- Optionally enables SWAP space in DO server and fixes a locale issue

Answer (score 22):

check out your phpinfo() script.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

missing the "php" behind the first "?" will give a blank page

Comment: On the first point of my question I already mentioned this. Still you are suggesting the same.

Comment: why do i make that mistake over and over?

Answer (score 6):

I think your php installation with apache is faulty. Thats why you can not see any php page in your webserver. Clean remove all the existing apps, like httpd,php,php-fpm,php-cli etc. and try to clean isntall in this order

```
yum install httpd -y
yum install php php-common php-cli php-gd php-curl php-fpm -y
```

then make sure you restart yout httpd server.

```
service httpd restart
```

Install  mod_fastcgi:

```
yum install  mod_fastcgi
```

Start the service:

```
service php-fpm start
```

Restart Apache:

```
service httpd restart
```

**5. Configuration of Apache with PHP-FPM**

Open the fastcgi.conf file:

```
nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/fastcgi.conf
```

Add this to the end of the file:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.shtml index.cgi index.php
                AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
                Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
                Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
                FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -host 127.0.0.1:9000 -pass-header Authorization
</IfModule>
```

After that search after "FastCgiWrapper" and make sure it's set to "off" then save the file.

The /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ directory must exist, so we create it:

```
mkdir /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
```

If mod_php is installed and enabled, we need to disable it so open the configuration at /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf:

```
nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf
```

Comment out the AddHandler and AddType lines so it looks like here:

```
#
# PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language which attempts to make it
# easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages.
#
<IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
</IfModule>
#
# Cause the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
#
#AddHandler php5-script .php
#AddType text/html .php
#
# Add index.php to the list of files that will be served as directory
# indexes.
#
DirectoryIndex index.php
#
# Uncomment the following line to allow PHP to pretty-print .phps
# files as PHP source code:
#
#AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Save the file and restart Apache:

```
service httpd restart
```

Comment: I will try re-installation with fast-cgi. Please hold-on, I will update you.

Comment: It looks like a bug in DO CentOS 6.5 image. Downgrading to 6.4 solves the issue.

Comment: Oh. I happened to use Centos 6.4 while installing LAMP. Glad your issue is resolved.

Comment: In my fedora 26 box, installed mod_php (yum -y install mod_php) to solve blank screen.

Answer (score 2):

Are you navigating to the php file directly? Or are you just going to the directory root?

If the later, Apache might not be recognizing .php as the directory index.

To test, try create a .htaccess file in your web root containing the following line:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but please avoid asking questions in the answer section. Use comment for that. Yes, I am going directly to the .php file and furthermore, `DirectoryIndex` is already set.

Comment: Apologies, commenting requires 50 reputation apparently, which as you can see I do not yet have.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue...
The problem is in the iptables. (**It seems like it**)

Try with:

```
service iptables stop
## check if it stop...
service iptables status
```

Then try to reload the page again.

If you had other solution please share.

[**edit**]
Restarting the iptables service is working for me.

Try:

```
service iptables restart
```

Comment: What led you to think it was iptables?

Answer (score 0):

Since everything looks at its default state, have you checked this part just for confirmation

`cat /etc/php.ini | grep log_errors`

If log_errors is disabled then enable it and check this below log after restarting httpd.
`/var/log/httpd/error_log`

--
Also check this part from php configuration. 
`cat /etc/php.ini | grep error_reporting`

This value should be enabled by default so that display_errors will work. 
`error_reporting  =  E_ALL`

Comment: `log_errors = On`
and
`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check the permissions of your file.
If you don't grant read-permission to public, Apache produces a blank page without showing any errors.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to repost an old thread...this is important.

I also was having these problems where no html response was outputting

After double-checking php.ini or my apache conf files and was still receiving no output, I later found out that I was suppressing the error of an include / require of a class, with `@`, which was nested within a constructor function. There was a syntax error in the included file, which stopped all output altogether when errors were thrown.

So, check your handlers first.
If you are storing all your output into vars first and you are including various scripts first that fail you'll have to see those errors. If you suppress file handler errors, you'll get a blank screen if you have a syntax error in the file.

Search your files for all instances of `@` in your php code. Then turn `@include "/path_to/script.php";` to `include "/path_to/script.php";` or anything `@$foo` into `$foo` as such var might reference a dependency that is causing your script to end with nothing showing in the httpd error log or in the http response.

Comment: Just FYI you never need to justify posting an answer. And these aren't threads. They're just questions and answers.

Comment: I am sure I did not hurt anybody's feelings