# Apache server can't execute php program

Tags: php, apache, server, ubuntu-server

I have a little problem. I have an OVH server that runs on Ubuntu 16.04 I configured all the main things: iptables, fail2ban, etc. 
But I have a problem with Apache. Indeed I installed it but when I want to access to a php program in my browser it doesn't work (I wrote this in my browser : http://my_server_ip/info.php
Here is a screen of what I have on my browser:

[Browser screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIAYc.png)

Also my php code is:

```
<?php 
    phpinfo();
?>
```

If someone could help me it would be really really kind :-)
Thank you!

P.S: Sorry for my poor english, I'm french so it's kind hard to speak correctly.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083506/getting-blank-php-page-over-apache

Comment: Try running a simple html file and see if it returns